# Dozer mapper to map without mapping file

Tags: jaxb, mapping, dozer

My source and target beans would have same number of objects and names of them. Also these objects would be created on the fly according to each category (models). Based on this case can I map my beans without a mapping file. If so can I have an example.

Comment: You can map programmatically, yes (via the API). Tutorials are the Dozer site...Have you looked there?

Comment: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/apimappings.html

Comment: Thanks @Mechkov I found this one helpful http://www.baeldung.com/dozer